# Node.js MySQL ETIMEDOUT error

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

After running node for a long time I get this error.
My program itself works perfectly fine.
What does it really mean? I can't find anything about it.
And most importantly how to prevent it?

```
Error: read ETIMEDOUT
at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
at TCP.onread (net.js:556:19)
--------------------
at Query.Sequence (/nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:15:20)
at new Query (/nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:12:12)
at Function.Connection.createQuery (/nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:48:10)
at Connection.query (/nodejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:100:26)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/nodejs/server.js:23:12)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit [as $emit] (events.js:95:17)
at SocketNamespace.handlePacket (/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:335:22)
at Manager.onClientMessage (/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:488:38)
at WebSocket.Transport.onMessage (/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transport.js:387:20)
at Parser.<anonymous> (/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:39:10)
```

I guess it has to do something with the `mysql` I'm using in my program because it refers to `Query.sequence` or something.
https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

The only line I can refer to that causes this error is where I create a query:

```
database.query("SELECT * FROM `...
```

Comment: TCP packets got lost on the way from the MySQL server or perhaps the server crashed or was too busy. node-mysql is waiting for a response from the server (TCP.onread) but it took too long so it got bored and stopped waiting and told you that it timed out (ETIMEDOUT). The solution is to reconnect when that happens and reissue the query.

Comment: How do I catch it when this happens?

Comment: The first parameter to the callback is `err`. If it exists, then there was an error. if `err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT'` then there was a timeout.

Comment: I already got that, this error is thrown from somewhere else I guess.